# Maven central archetype catalog

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-archetype

I deployed a maven archetype to sonatype 24 hours ago. While the artifacts are available in repo1, the archetype is not listed in

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

How can I get it there? Note that the archetype is in

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/archetype-catalog.xml

I thought that meant it would automatically go to Maven central's archetype catalog, so what am I missing?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

It should get merged into the archetype-catalog. Check with the [support team for the Central Repository](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/help.html) to check if something is wrong with that.